# Angular 2 checkbox check all

Tags: angular

I have a list to check projectnames. On the bottom I want to place a checkbox to check or uncheck them all. I think I need an *ngIf (if checked) with an *ngFor loop (check all) but this is quite the challenge... I cannot figure out how I should procede with this. Do I use (checked) or something or *ngIf="(checked)" and then use an *ngFor loop to set project.isChecked. I cannot get inside the logic of this.

```
<div id="drp-project-select">
        <div class="scroller" [hidden]="!showMenu">
            <div id="search-wrapper">
                <i class="fa fa-search fa-xs"></i>
                <input [(ngModel)]="searchTerm" type="text" placeholder="Zoek op naam..." #search>
            </div>   
            <ul>
                <li *ngFor="#project of projectdata.LoginResponse?.ProjectVM | searchpipe:'Project':search.value">
                    <label class="checkbox-label" >
                        <input type="checkbox" class="dropdown-checkbox" [(ngModel)]="project.isChecked" (change)="addProject(project)" >
                        <span>{{project.Project}}</span>
                    </label>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="bottom-data" [hidden]="!showMenu">
            <label><input type="checkbox" id="bottom-checkbox"></label>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use a control on the "check / uncheck all" checkbox to be notified when the user checks or unchecks:

```
<input type="checkbox" [ngFormControl]="allCtrl"/>
```

`allCtrl` is initialized within the constructor of the component. Then you could register against the `valueChanges` property of this control to be notified of updates and update the `isChecked` fields accordingly:

```
constructor() {
  this.allCtrl = new Control();
  this.allCtrl.valueChanges.subscribe(
    (val) => {
      this.projectdata.LoginResponse.ProjectVM.forEach((project) => {
        project.isChecked = val;
      });
    });
}
```

Comment: I got an error saying "unexpected token ." After careful inspection I wondered if the elvis operator worked, and it didn't. The elvis operator was removed from the constructor and it works great now :)
Would you mind editing your answer so if this post gets looked up in the future the operator won't throw? Then I can mark your answer as the correct one.

Comment: Oh my god. It's a typo. The Elvis operator can only be used with expressions in the view not in the TypeScript code... Thanks for pointing this out! I updated my answer.

Comment: Where does `Control` come from?

Comment: Thanks for this; this is a better refactor than the `$(this).click()` that's in the code currently. However, my problem is that when calling the event for the individual checkboxes, the `isChecked` property hasn't yet updated.